# HTAccess redirect Based on Query Parameter Fails?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

am trying to redirect (HTAccess) a URL based on the existance of a Querystring Paramater "ref". Only redirect when this exists with the prefix folder of "TMP" and page name "domain.html".
The problem is that the redirect is working, but the Querystring isnt being passed on

e.g.
http://www.olddomain.com/TMP/domain.html?ref=website-reference.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/TMP/domain\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/?ref=%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=
RewriteRule ^TMP/domain\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

With the same query string.

Comment: worked first time, thank you so much for your excellent reply.